# Properly typed factory for FastAPI and Pydantic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I have been developing my first API using FastAPI/SQLAlchemy. I have been using the same four methods (Get One, Get All, Post, Delete) for multiple different entities in the database, thus creating a lot of repeated code. For example, the code below shows the methods for a Fungus entity.

```py
from typing import List, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING: from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import models.fungus as models
import schemas.fungus as schemas

async def create_fungus(fungus: schemas.CreateFungus, db: "Session") -> schemas.Fungus:
    fungus = models.Fungus(**fungus.dict())
    db.add(fungus)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(fungus)
    return schemas.Fungus.from_orm(fungus)

async def get_all_fungi(db: "Session") -> List[schemas.Fungus]:
    fungi = db.query(models.Fungus).limit(25).all()
    return [schemas.Fungus.from_orm(fungus) for fungus in fungi]


async def get_fungus(fungus_id: str, db: "Session") -> schemas.Fungus:
    fungus = db.query(models.Fungus).filter(models.Fungus.internal_id == fungus_id).first()
    return fungus


async def delete_fungus(fungus_id: str, db: "Session") -> int:
    num_rows = db.query(models.Fungus).filter_by(id=fungus_id).delete()
    db.commit()
    return num_rows
```

I have been trying to come up with an abstract design pattern with an interface class that implements these four methods independent from the entity.

However, from my understanding new Python standards and FastAPI require Python to be typed. So, how would I type the return types of these functions, instead of `schemas.Fungus`, or the parameters `schemas.CreateFungus` or `models.Fungus`?

What I have thought is that I could use the type of these values, which are `<class 'pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass'>` and `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api.DeclarativeMeta'>`. However I am not sure if this is correct or encouraged.

Comment: It is important to stress that there is no _requirement_ for Python to be typed in general, nor is there such a requirement in FastAPI per se. It is just (thankfully) becoming best practice to properly annotate Python code and FastAPI can make clever use of annotations in some instances. Pydantic is special in that the model field types **must** be annotated because those annotations are used to construct the fields at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to go the *abstract* route. But a **generic** interface for those common CRUD operations is certainly possible.

You could write your own [generic class](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) that is (for example) parameterized by

1. the ORM model (from SQLAlchemy) to use for database transactions,
2. the "response" model (from Pydantic) for things like getting/listing objects, and
3. the "create" model (from Pydantic) for adding new data.

Here is an example of such a class that is based on what you did with the fungi models:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeMeta, Session

GetModel = TypeVar("GetModel", bound=BaseModel)
CreateModel = TypeVar("CreateModel", bound=BaseModel)
ORM = TypeVar("ORM", bound=DeclarativeMeta)


class CRUDInterface(Generic[ORM, GetModel, CreateModel]):
    orm_model: ORM
    get_model: type[GetModel]
    create_model: type[CreateModel]

    def __init__(
        self,
        orm_model: ORM,
        get_model: type[GetModel],
        create_model: type[CreateModel],
        db_id_field: str = "id",
    ) -> None:
        self.orm_model = orm_model
        self.get_model = get_model
        self.create_model = create_model
        self.db_id_field = db_id_field

    def create(self, data: CreateModel, db: Session) -> GetModel:
        new_instance = self.orm_model(**data.dict())
        db.add(new_instance)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(new_instance)
        return self.get_model.from_orm(new_instance)

    def list(self, db: Session, limit: int = 25) -> list[GetModel]:
        objects = db.query(self.orm_model).limit(limit).all()
        return [self.get_model.from_orm(obj) for obj in objects]

    def get(self, id_: int, db: Session) -> GetModel:
        where = getattr(self.orm_model, self.db_id_field) == id_
        obj = db.query(self.orm_model).filter(where).first()
        return self.get_model.from_orm(obj)

    def delete(self, id_: int, db: Session) -> int:
        filter_kwargs = {self.db_id_field: id_}
        num_rows = db.query(self.orm_model).filter_by(**filter_kwargs).delete()
        db.commit()
        return num_rows
```

Now this class is fully generic in terms of the models involved in the CRUD operations you showed in your example, which means upon instantiation, an object of `CRUDInterface` will be properly typed in its methods, and as a bonus there is no need to pass around the *specific* models after initialization. The models are simply saved as instance attributes.

Assume now that you have the following models: (simplified)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeMeta, declarative_base


ORMBase: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()


class Fungus(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class CreateFungus(BaseModel):
    name: str


class FungusORM(ORMBase):
    __tablename__ = "fungus"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

Here is a little usage demo with those models:

```py
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# ... import CRUDInterface, ORMBase, FungusORM, Fungus, CreateFungus


def main() -> None:
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///", echo=True)
    ORMBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
    fungus_crud = CRUDInterface(FungusORM, Fungus, CreateFungus)
    with Session(engine) as db:
        mushroom = fungus_crud.create(CreateFungus(name="oyster mushroom"), db)
        reveal_type(mushroom)
        assert mushroom.id == 1

        same_mushroom = fungus_crud.get(1, db)
        reveal_type(same_mushroom)
        assert mushroom == same_mushroom

        all_mushrooms = fungus_crud.list(db)
        reveal_type(all_mushrooms)
        assert all_mushrooms[0] == mushroom

        num_deleted = fungus_crud.delete(1, db)
        assert num_deleted == 1
        all_mushrooms = fungus_crud.list(db)
        assert len(all_mushrooms) == 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This executes without error and the generated SQL queries are as we would expect. Moreover, running `mypy --strict` over this code yields no errors (at least with the [SQLAlchemy Mypy plugin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/mypy.html)) and reveals the *types* as expected, too:

```
note: Revealed type is "Fungus"
note: Revealed type is "Fungus"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[Fungus]"
```

This clearly demonstrates the advantage of using generics over simply annotating with the common base classes or meta classes.

If you just annotated, say `CRUDInterface.get` with `pydantic.BaseModel`, a type checker would never be able to tell you what *specific* model instance will be returned. In practice, this means your IDE will not give you any suggestions about *specific* methods/attributes of e.g. the `Fungus` model.

Obviously, there is a lot more you can do with generics in this context. You can also make the existing methods more flexible and so on. But this example should at least get you started.